# CSS absolute position

Tags: html, css, position

If an HTML element has following CSS property, what would be its position on the screen?

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that most browsers actually has the element **fill the window** *(or the parent element, if the parent element has absolute or relative position)*

If you add a `width` declaration to the CSS, however, the `left` will be enforced and the `right` will be ignored.

If you add a `height` declaration, the `bottom` will be ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/tjFvL/

Comment: yes, i know it does not make much sense, thats why I asked the question. I saw this code in a demo, in which the author used this for a :target.

Comment: Here, http://downloads.sixrevisions.com/css-light-box/source.html check the .lightbox:target. Do you suggest better alternative for that?

Comment: There's a number of articles that recommend doing this - example http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Answer (score 1):

If height and width are specified, it will be `top left` in all major browsers. If `top` is not specified, then it will be `bottom left`. In other words, `top` takes precedence over `bottom` and `left` takes precedence over `right`.

If you don't have height and width set (defaulting to `auto`), then the the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` are used to calculate them. If your parent container is `20px` by `20px` and you have:

```
{
top: 5px;
bottom:0;
left:5px;
right:0;
position:absolute;
}
```

then the element will be `15px` by `15px`, i.e.

**([height of parent] - [top] - [bottom] by [width of parent] - [left] - [right])**

positioned at `top: 5px left:5px` within the parent container.

Comment: That is true, only if `width` or `height` is added. If you have `left` and `right`, but not `width`, both `left`and `right` are honored.

Comment: @atornblad imho, they are not. Container is placed in top left corner of the parent and then sized using the inherited height and width.

Comment: That is just wrong. Absolutely positioned elements do **not** have width:100% by default. Also, default height is `auto` - not `100%`

Answer (score 1):

It would fill its parent container. The position on the screen would therefore be top/left: 0, 0

Answer (score 0):

Its top left corner will be in the top left corner of the enclosing positioned element or, in the absence of such an element, in the top left corner of the canvas. Its width and height will be the same as those of the enclosing positioned element (or the canvas).

Answer (score 0):

If this  code

```
 div{   
   position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
}
```

in the css means it's takes the entry `width & height of the screen` or it's `parent`.

you can achieve same effect with `width:100%` & `height:100%;` like this:

```
div{   
       position: absolute; 
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

but both have major difference in first example if you `add padding & border` on the element then they are `not add` to `width & height` to that element but in second they `add padding & border value in the height & width`.

Check these two example in which only `padding & border` create huge different.

### http://jsfiddle.net/qzNKd/2/

&

### http://jsfiddle.net/FQLdm/3/

Answer (score 0):

Its working as

```
position:absolute; 
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The element will fill the entire containing block content area. Its content area is defined by width and height, and no padding or anything else. Its containing block is nearest positioned -non static- ancestor.

For instance, `top: 0` is saying to the element to have an offset 0 from the top of its containing block. So to start at the begining of its content area. And `bottom: 0` is saying to spread the length until reach left extrem of the content area.

The same for `right` and `left`.

Of course, second declaration is ignored if you declare an explicit `width` or `height`.

It do make sense. As the specification says:

> The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties. These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings. Also, though absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

[Link to specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)

The key is *possibly size*.